# How to pair rows by status (someone entered and then exited) in mysql

Tags: mysql, rows, procedure

I have a table *user_status*, where I insert rows: *who*, *status* (Entered/Exited), *what time*. Table looks like this:

```
id  user_id  status   status_date
94  5        Entered  2015-03-30 10:43:44
95  5        Exited   2015-03-30 10:47:38
96  5        Entered  2015-03-30 10:49:12
97  3        Entered  2015-03-30 10:51:14
98  3        Exited   2015-03-30 11:04:12
99  5        Exited   2015-03-30 11:16:50
100 3        Entered  2015-03-30 11:20:48
101 5        Entered  2015-03-30 11:21:37
102 2        Exited   2015-03-30 11:24:47
103 2        Entered  2015-03-30 11:25:01
```

Now I want to create procedure that, pairs rows for specific user matching his/her Entered with Exited status and returns temporary table. The result should be like this:

```
id  user_id  status_date_start    status_date_end
1  5         2015-03-30 10:43:44  2015-03-30 10:47:38
2  5         2015-03-30 10:49:12  2015-03-30 11:16:50
3  3         2015-03-30 10:51:14  2015-03-30 11:04:12
...
```

I tried double inner join, cursors on *user_status* but I didn't manage. Please help

Comment: I am doing a project just like you are doing now, I store them as full and raw table. For raw table, I store A_I, user_id, status_date. My website code will determine it is entering or exiting. If it is entering, I will `INSERT INTO full VALUES ('', user_id, last_id, '')` which last_id is the A_I return from raw table. If it is exiting, I will `UPDATE full SET status_date_end = last_id WHERE id = this_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just played around with this a little and got it to work with an extra select in the query.

```
-- set up some test data
GO 
DECLARE @moves TABLE
    (
        id INT,
        user_id INT,
        status NVARCHAR(MAX),
        status_date DATETIME
    )

INSERT INTO @moves VALUES (94, 5 , 'Entered', '2015-03-30 10:43:44')
INSERT INTO @moves VALUES (95, 5 , 'Exited', ' 2015-03-30 10:47:38')
INSERT INTO @moves VALUES (96, 5 , 'Entered', '2015-03-30 10:49:12')
INSERT INTO @moves VALUES (97, 3 , 'Entered', '2015-03-30 10:51:14')
INSERT INTO @moves VALUES (98, 3 , 'Exited', '2015-03-30 11:04:12')
INSERT INTO @moves VALUES (99, 5 , 'Exited', '2015-03-30 11:16:50')

-- original data --
SELECT * FROM @moves


-- selecting the exit date into the original data --
SELECT 
    m.id
    ,m.user_id
    ,m.status_date
    ,(
        SELECT TOP 1  status_date
        FROM @moves x 
        WHERE x.user_id = m.user_id
        AND x.status = 'Exited'
        AND x.id > m.id
    ) as 'exit'
FROM @moves m  
WHERE m.status ='Entered'
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I use mysql so the only change was to change TOP 1 to LIMIT 1 and it works! Thanks @JensB, you're awesome